# Can`t find wifi networks on 13 channel

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, broadcom

I have turned on access point on my phone(Xiaomi Redmi 6A), i verified that I can connect on non-linux devices. But my ubuntu(20.04) laptop doesn't find my network. After that I tried to find my network in `airodump-ng` and found it on 13 channel with about 19 beacons in 9 minutes.
Here is some useful info:

```
# lshw output 
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43225 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlp8s0
       version: 01
       serial: 78:e4:00:f1:b6:b4
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:f1000000-f1003fff

#lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS880 Host Bridge
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (ext gfx port 0)
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 41)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller (rev 40)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller (rev 40)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Link Control
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Park [Mobility Radeon HD 5430/5450/5470]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cedar HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5400/6300/7300 Series]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01)
08:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43225 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)



# iw phy
Wiphy phy0
    max # scan SSIDs: 1
    max scan IEs length: 0 bytes
    max # sched scan SSIDs: 0
    max # match sets: 0
    max # scan plans: 1
    max scan plan interval: -1
    max scan plan iterations: 0
    Retry short limit: 7
    Retry long limit: 4
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Supported Ciphers:
        * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
        * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
        * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
        * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)
        * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
    Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
    Band 1:
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 1.0 Mbps
            * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
    Band 2:
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 5160 MHz [32] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5170 MHz [34] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5180 MHz [36] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5190 MHz [38] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5200 MHz [40] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5210 MHz [42] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5220 MHz [44] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5230 MHz [46] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5240 MHz [48] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5250 MHz [50] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5260 MHz [52] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5270 MHz [54] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5280 MHz [56] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5290 MHz [58] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5300 MHz [60] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5310 MHz [62] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5320 MHz [64] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5330 MHz [66] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5340 MHz [68] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5350 MHz [70] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5360 MHz [72] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5370 MHz [74] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5380 MHz [76] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5390 MHz [78] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5400 MHz [80] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5410 MHz [82] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5420 MHz [84] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5430 MHz [86] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5440 MHz [88] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5450 MHz [90] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5460 MHz [92] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5470 MHz [94] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5480 MHz [96] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5490 MHz [98] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5500 MHz [100] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5510 MHz [102] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5520 MHz [104] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5530 MHz [106] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5540 MHz [108] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5550 MHz [110] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5560 MHz [112] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5570 MHz [114] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5580 MHz [116] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5590 MHz [118] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5600 MHz [120] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5610 MHz [122] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5620 MHz [124] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5630 MHz [126] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5640 MHz [128] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5650 MHz [130] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5660 MHz [132] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5670 MHz [134] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5680 MHz [136] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5690 MHz [138] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5700 MHz [140] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5710 MHz [142] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5720 MHz [144] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5725 MHz [145] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5730 MHz [146] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5735 MHz [147] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5740 MHz [148] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5745 MHz [149] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5750 MHz [150] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5755 MHz [151] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5760 MHz [152] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5765 MHz [153] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5770 MHz [154] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5775 MHz [155] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5780 MHz [156] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5785 MHz [157] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5790 MHz [158] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5795 MHz [159] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5800 MHz [160] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5805 MHz [161] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5810 MHz [162] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5815 MHz [163] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5820 MHz [164] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5825 MHz [165] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5830 MHz [166] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5840 MHz [168] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5850 MHz [170] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5860 MHz [172] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5870 MHz [174] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5880 MHz [176] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5890 MHz [178] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5900 MHz [180] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5910 MHz [182] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5920 MHz [184] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5930 MHz [186] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5940 MHz [188] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5950 MHz [190] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5960 MHz [192] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5970 MHz [194] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5980 MHz [196] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5990 MHz [198] (30.0 dBm)
            * 6000 MHz [200] (30.0 dBm)
            * 6010 MHz [202] (30.0 dBm)
            * 6020 MHz [204] (30.0 dBm)
            * 6030 MHz [206] (30.0 dBm)
            * 6040 MHz [208] (30.0 dBm)
            * 6050 MHz [210] (30.0 dBm)
            * 6060 MHz [212] (30.0 dBm)
            * 6070 MHz [214] (30.0 dBm)
            * 6080 MHz [216] (30.0 dBm)
            * 6090 MHz [218] (30.0 dBm)
            * 6100 MHz [220] (30.0 dBm)
            * 6110 MHz [222] (30.0 dBm)
            * 6120 MHz [224] (30.0 dBm)
            * 6130 MHz [226] (30.0 dBm)
            * 6140 MHz [228] (30.0 dBm)
    Supported commands:
         * set_interface
         * new_key
         * join_ibss
         * set_pmksa
         * del_pmksa
         * flush_pmksa
         * connect
         * disconnect
    software interface modes (can always be added):
    interface combinations are not supported
    Device supports scan flush.
    Supported extended features:

# iw dev
phy#0
    Interface wlp8s0
        ifindex 3
        wdev 0x1
        addr 78:e4:00:f1:b6:b4
        type managed

#iw reg get
global
country BY: DFS-ETSI
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5490 - 5710 @ 160), (N/A, 27), (0 ms), DFS

#ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/0000:08:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000014E4d00004357sv0000105Bsd0000E021bc02sc80i00
vendor   : Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
model    : BCM43225 802.11b/g/n (T77H103.00 Wireless Half-size Mini PCIe Card)
driver   : bcmwl-kernel-source - distro non-free

#lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 81920  4
cmac                   16384  13
algif_hash             16384  6
algif_skcipher         16384  6
af_alg                 24576  26 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
bnep                   24576  3
uvcvideo               98304  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
ec_sys                 16384  0
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
btusb                  57344  0
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
videobuf2_common       49152  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                24576  1 btusb
videodev              225280  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
bluetooth             581632  33 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
mc                     53248  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
ecc                    28672  1 ecdh_generic
xt_CHECKSUM            16384  1
xt_MASQUERADE          20480  3
xt_conntrack           16384  1
ipt_REJECT             16384  2
nf_reject_ipv4         16384  1 ipt_REJECT
xt_tcpudp              20480  9
ip6table_mangle        16384  1
ip6table_nat           16384  1
iptable_mangle         16384  1
iptable_nat            16384  1
nf_nat                 40960  3 ip6table_nat,iptable_nat,xt_MASQUERADE
nf_conntrack          139264  3 xt_conntrack,nf_nat,xt_MASQUERADE
nf_defrag_ipv6         24576  1 nf_conntrack
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack
libcrc32c              16384  2 nf_conntrack,nf_nat
nf_tables             135168  0
nfnetlink              16384  1 nf_tables
ip6table_filter        16384  1
ip6_tables             32768  3 ip6table_filter,ip6table_nat,ip6table_mangle
iptable_filter         16384  1
bpfilter               32768  0
bridge                176128  0
stp                    16384  1 bridge
llc                    16384  2 bridge,stp
aufs                  262144  0
overlay               114688  0
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_hda_codec_realtek   118784  1
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
edac_mce_amd           32768  0
snd_hda_intel          53248  6
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  1 snd_hda_intel
wl                   6455296  0
joydev                 24576  0
snd_hda_codec         131072  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
input_leds             16384  0
snd_hda_core           90112  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
serio_raw              20480  0
acer_wmi               24576  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 acer_wmi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
k10temp                16384  0
snd_pcm               106496  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    90112  22 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
cfg80211              704512  1 wl
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mac_hid                16384  0
kvm_amd                98304  0
ccp                    86016  1 kvm_amd
kvm                   663552  1 kvm_amd
binfmt_misc            24576  1
sch_fq_codel           20480  5
parport_pc             40960  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                53248  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              32768  3 iptable_filter,iptable_nat,iptable_mangle
x_tables               40960  11 ip6table_filter,xt_conntrack,iptable_filter,xt_tcpudp,xt_CHECKSUM,ip6_tables,ipt_REJECT,ip_tables,ip6table_mangle,xt_MASQUERADE,iptable_mangle
autofs4                45056  2
hid_logitech_hidpp     40960  0
hid_logitech_dj        24576  0
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 57344  1 hid_logitech_dj
hid                   131072  4 usbhid,hid_generic,hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp
radeon               1474560  24
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 radeon
ttm                   106496  1 radeon
pata_acpi              16384  0
psmouse               155648  0
drm_kms_helper        184320  1 radeon
pata_atiixp            16384  0
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
i2c_piix4              28672  0
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
broadcom               24576  1
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
bcm_phy_lib            16384  1 broadcom
drm                   491520  13 drm_kms_helper,radeon,ttm
tg3                   172032  0
ahci                   40960  1
libahci                32768  1 ahci
video                  49152  1 acer_wmi
wmi                    32768  2 acer_wmi,wmi_bmof

#iw wlp8s0 scan
BSS 70:72:3c:12:de:58(on wlp8s0) # This is not my wifi
    TSF: 0 usec (0d, 00:00:00)
    freq: 2412
    beacon interval: 100 TUs
    capability: ESS Privacy ShortPreamble ShortSlotTime (0x0431)
    signal: -83.00 dBm
    last seen: 11032 ms ago
    SSID: I***
    Supported rates: 1.0* 2.0* 5.5* 11.0* 9.0 18.0 36.0 54.0 
    DS Parameter set: channel 1
    Extended supported rates: 6.0 12.0 24.0 48.0 
    Country: BY Environment: Indoor/Outdoor
        Channels [1 - 13] @ 20 dBm
    TIM: DTIM Count 0 DTIM Period 1 Bitmap Control 0x0 Bitmap[0] 0x22
    RSN:     * Version: 1
         * Group cipher: TKIP
         * Pairwise ciphers: TKIP CCMP
         * Authentication suites: PSK
         * Capabilities: 1-PTKSA-RC 1-GTKSA-RC (0x0000)
    WPS:     * Version: 1.0
         * Wi-Fi Protected Setup State: 2 (Configured)
         * UUID: bc329e00-1dd8-11b2-8601-70723c12de58
         * RF Bands: 0x1
         * Unknown TLV (0x1049, 6 bytes): 00 37 2a 00 01 20
    ERP: <no flags>
    HT capabilities:
        Capabilities: 0x118e
            HT20/HT40
            SM Power Save disabled
            TX STBC
            RX STBC 1-stream
            Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: No restriction (0x00)
        HT RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15, 32
        HT TX MCS rate indexes are undefined
    HT operation:
         * primary channel: 1
         * secondary channel offset: above
         * STA channel width: any
         * RIFS: 0
         * HT protection: 20 MHz
         * non-GF present: 1
         * OBSS non-GF present: 0
         * dual beacon: 0
         * dual CTS protection: 0
         * STBC beacon: 0
         * L-SIG TXOP Prot: 0
         * PCO active: 0
         * PCO phase: 0
    Overlapping BSS scan params:
         * passive dwell: 20 TUs
         * active dwell: 10 TUs
         * channel width trigger scan interval: 300 s
         * scan passive total per channel: 200 TUs
         * scan active total per channel: 20 TUs
         * BSS width channel transition delay factor: 5
         * OBSS Scan Activity Threshold: 0.25 %
    Extended capabilities:
         * HT Information Exchange Supported
    WMM:     * Parameter version 1
         * BE: CW 15-1023, AIFSN 3
         * BK: CW 15-1023, AIFSN 7
         * VI: CW 7-15, AIFSN 2, TXOP 3008 usec
         * VO: CW 3-7, AIFSN 2, TXOP 1504 usec
    BSS Load:
         * station count: 2
         * channel utilisation: 15/255
         * available admission capacity: 31250 [*32us]

#dmesg | grep wl 
[   10.347080] wl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   10.347088] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[   10.647638] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   10.834329] wlan0: Broadcom BCM4357 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.271 (r587334)
[   21.203824] wl 0000:08:00.0 wlp8s0: renamed from wlan0
[ 2521.001083] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : 
[ 2521.001090] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_tx_power : 

#dmesg | grep 80211

[    9.948749] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[    9.996862] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[ 2521.001090] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_tx_power :
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `iw list`.

Comment: `iw list` output same as `iw phy`